# Handling timeouts in Webview

Tags: cocoa, webkit

Suppose you have a webview that would load a page, how would you handle the situation if the page fails to load, for instance, in 20 seconds?

More specifically which WebView delegate method is called when the such situation occurs?

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFailProvisionalLoadWithError:(NSError *)error forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

or

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

Comment: are you asking technically how could it be handled, or practically how might it be handled?

Answer (score 2):

The distinction pointed out by Michael is important. In any case, if you register as a delegate for the UIWebView, you might end receiving the – webView:didFailLoadWithError: call. Here you can produce an UIAlertView with the error, or inject some pre-canned html or another view. It greatly depends on what you want to show.

Comment: The same also goes for WebView. You would run an NSAlert if the WebView fails to load its main resource.